# How to cache content if there is no Cache-Control header in the response NGINX

Tags: nginx, caching

I have got a Ubuntu instance with NGINX installed and configured as a forward proxy on one host for my application on a different host.
My app is making GET requests to NGINX which is making another GET requests to external server (URL to this server is specified in the request) and returning the response to the application.
NGINX is supposed to cache the response from the external server.
I need to respect the Cache-Control header from the response (cache the response that long as this header says) BUT! When there is no Cache-Control header in the response, it must be cached for 12h, what to do to achieve it?
Thanks! :)

Here is my actual config:

```
proxy_cache_path /tmp/nginx_cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_cache:100m max_size=2m inactive=12h use_temp_path=off;
location ~* {
                resolver xx.xx.x.xxx;
                proxy_cache my_cache;
                add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
                if ($http_x_example_use_https = '1') {
                        proxy_pass https://$host;
                }
                if ($http_x_example_use_https = '0') {
                        proxy_pass http://$host;
                }
                
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_connect_timeout   4;
                proxy_send_timeout      4;
                proxy_read_timeout      4;
                send_timeout 4;
                proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
                proxy_cache_lock on;
        }
```

PS Any thoughts to improve this config or change something? :)

Answer (score 1):

I think I have solved my problem using:

```
proxy_cache_valid 200 12h;
```

And when the Cache-Control header is present, it shouldn't be overwritten by this directive above.

NGINX documentation:

> Parameters of caching can also be set directly in the response header. This has higher priority than setting of caching time using the directive.
> If the header does not include the “X-Accel-Expires” field, parameters of caching may be set in the header fields “Expires” or “Cache-Control”.